# PHP fgetcsv() where source file doesn't have an enclosure character?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have an input CSV where the "columns" aren't enclosed in anything.

File contents ($input = fopen(*filename*);):

```
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g
    9,8,7,6,5,4,3
    z,y,x,w,v,u,t
```

I'm having problems getting fgetcsv() to work because there isn't an enclosure around the values.

```
    while($row = fgetcsv($input)) {
      print_r($row);
    }
```

Results in:

```
1111
```

I've tried some basic things that I could think of off the top of my head:

```
fgetcsc($file, 0, ',', '\');

fgetcsc($file, 0, ',', '');
```

Any ideas for a work around? Manually editing my input file isn't really an option as it's several millions of lines.

Comment: Duh... I should just use explode(). Sorry, it's Friday...

Comment: `fgetcsv` does not depend on the presence of quotes/enclosures.

Comment: Based on the responses, and further testing, I believe my input file is corrupt somehow, or possibly in a very strange character encoding? Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: This happened to me when there was a single double quote as a value in a column. Can't trust external data sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is. `fgetcsv` and `str_getcsv` also work with columns sans quotes:

```
print_r(str_getcsv('1,2,3,4,5,6,7'));
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

The quotes are optional and only intended for CSV which can have the column delimiter within the values:

```
 column1, "Column 2 with , comma inside", colum3
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I've got another problem then. Thanks!

Comment: If it's really the file (sometimes linebreak type can be at fault), then try importing it on OpenOffice and writing back as .CSV file. Sometimes workarounds are the best option.

Comment: The file is too big to be opened by any Office suite I know of... several million lines (rows). It's a database dump essentially.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use those two last parameters at all, they are optional. Just use:

```
fgetcsv($file, 1000);
```

This will automatically assume that the delimiter is a comma. Also the length must not be 0 but a positive number of characters that should be read.

Alternatively: You don't have to rely on `fgetcsv`, you can just use `explode`:

```
$values = explode(",", $row);
```

Comment: PHP 5.0.4 and later the length parameter is optional, although specifying a length should be quicker. Using 0 does no length limit.

Answer (score 1):

a more proper way of doing this is to change the enclosure value to something rarely used (or not at all used).

the best variation of such, I have found, would be the chr(0) character.

```
fgetcsv($handle, null, "\t", chr(0))
```

works fine for me and should not break, unless you have a very extreme case of CSV data.